# Configuring Postfix with multiple virtualhosts

Tags: apache2, email, postfix

I am trying to set up Postfix for a website I am hosting, but the machine is hosting multiple sites. Drupal and wordpress sites (which might be important, I'm not sure).

I am testing it out by running some sendmail commands and it is actually sending me the mail. The domain (@whatever.com) is what I specified in the config process.

Is there a way to have the domain change depending on what Virtualhost (site) is sending the mail? So if myweb.org send mail it comes from @myweb.org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sender of an email is not set by Postfix. It is set by the mail agent, which specifies it in the *From* header. (There are some additional technicalities related to the Sender of the envelope, but these are probably not relevant.)

When you were testing your setup using the `sendmail` command, you weren't setting the *From* header, but left it to Postfix to complete the sender address. That's when it uses the *mailhost* value or some other mechanism to add a domain name to the unqualified system user name.

Virtual hosts won't normally send mail as an unqualified system user. In Drupal or Wordpress you configure a fully qualified sender address to be used when the system sends email.

(Obviously, if you are also hosting *incoming* mail for the hosted domains, then your Postfix will need a bunch of additional configuration, but your question suggests you're only concerned with outbound mail.)

Comment: Man I've been making all this email stuff alot harder than it needed to be. Thanks for your help.